# Http sessions and hibernate combined use

Tags: hibernate, jsp, httpsession

/*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

```
  package Registration;
  import Pojos.Users;
  import Pojos.hiber;
  import java.io.IOException;
  import java.io.PrintWriter;
  import javax.servlet.ServletException;
  import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
  import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
  import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
  import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
  import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession; 
  import org.hibernate.Session;
  import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
  import org.hibernate.Transaction;

/**
*
* @author parag
 */


   @WebServlet(name="Reg",urlPatterns={"/Reg"})

   public class Reg extends HttpServlet{
   protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse    response) 
        throws ServletException,IOException
    {
    response.setContentType("text/html; charset=UTF-8");

    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    try{
        out.println("<html>");
        out.println("<head>");
        out.println("<title>Servlet Registration </title>");
        out.println("</head>");
        out.println("<body>");
        out.println("<h1>Servlet Registration</h1>");
        out.println("</body>");
        out.println("</html>");

    }
    finally{
        out.close();
    }
   }




   @Override
   protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
       throws ServletException,IOException
  {
   processRequest(request, response);
  }


  @Override
  protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
       throws ServletException, IOException
   {
   PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();


   String uname , fname ,lname, pwd , email , address , country , gender , hobby ,         education,image;


    uname = request.getParameter("user_name");

    fname = request.getParameter("fname");
    lname = request.getParameter("lname");
    pwd = request.getParameter("pass");

    String p = request.getParameter("phone");



    email =request.getParameter("em");

    address = request.getParameter("add");
    country = request.getParameter("country");
    gender = request.getParameter("gender");

    hobby = request.getParameter("hobby");

    education = request.getParameter("edu");

    String d = request.getParameter("sltdate");
    String m = request.getParameter("sltmonth");
    String y = request.getParameter("sltyear");

    String bdate = d+"--"+m+"--"+y;
  try{

    SessionFactory sessionFactory = hiber.getSessionFactory();
    Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
    Users user = new Users();


    user.setUserName(uname);
    user.setFirstName(fname);
    user.setLastName(lname);
    user.setPassword(pwd);
    user.setPhoneNo(p);
    user.setProfPic(null);
    user.setEmail(email);
    user.setAddress(address);
    user.setBirthdate(bdate);
    user.setCountry(country);
    user.setGender(gender);
    user.setHobby(hobby);
    user.setEducation(education);

    session.save(user);

    Transaction transaction = session.beginTransaction();


    if (true){

   transaction.commit();

   HttpSession session1 = request.getSession(true);

   session1.setAttribute("un", uname);

    response.sendRedirect("image_upload.jsp");
    }
    out.println("okkkk");
    session.close();

    //response.sendRedirect("index.jsp");



}catch(Exception e){
    out.println("Error" +e.getMessage());

}


}

}
```

This is the servlet where i have defined http session variables, but on other page i am not getting this session variables. What to do ?

Comment: Session is created automatically for each user when they request something. just get it from the request object request.getSession()

Comment: post some code of how you tried to do it, this will help get an answer

Comment: Hi jhadesdev, i have given the code , what i want to know is why i am not getting the http session variables on the other pages ? And i also want to know how to store images through hibernate .Suggest me any link from where i can get that. Thank You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To retrieve objects stored in the session within your jsp if they are string you could do this.

```
<input type="text" value="${sessionScope.un}" />
```

OR

```
<% String username = (String)request.getSession().getAttribute("un"); %>
```

Also creation of HibernateFactory is a very expensive process consider dont create in each request.

Comment: Thanks Koitoer.. I got this and i have also a problem in storing image . How to do this ?

Comment: It is more complicated problem first you need to upload the file that you want to store, then the uploaded file *bytes representation need to be stored in a BLOB within the database, start with the first approach to upload a file and obtain the bytes in the servlet as you using Servlet3, consider using @Multipart , this is a good starting point.  http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/glrbb.html

Comment: Hey Koitoer I have posted a question what i want to know ai this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21772181/storing-image-in-table-using-commons-fileupload     Please guid me ...